# Set the image for switch button in flutter

Tags: flutter

How do I set the image for a switch button in flutter using the activeThumbImage property? I am a little confused on how to set the ImageProvider value for this property? Is there any example that I could look at that implements the activeThumbImage property of the Switch widget?

Comment: you can watch this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TYNbMnaEnmA

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use an `AssetImage` or `NetworkImage` to get an `ImageProvider` that is suitable for use as an `activeThumbImage`. Learn more about asset images in the [Adding Assets and Images in Flutter](https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/) tutorial.

[image: vi]   [image: emacs]

Here is some example code that draws the above `Switch`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePageState createState() => new MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  bool _enabled;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Switch(
          value: _enabled,
          onChanged: (bool value) {
            setState(() {
              _enabled = value;
            });
          },
          activeThumbImage: new NetworkImage('https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2015-10/pngR9b4lzUy39.png'),
          inactiveThumbImage: new NetworkImage('http://wolfrosch.com/_img/works/goodies/icon/vim@2x'),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: new ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
    ),
    home: new MyHomePage(),
  ));
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a canvas to draw my own active and inactive thumb images?  I tried using PictureRecorder  as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50652767/is-it-possible-to-draw-an-image-with-dart-flutter to create an image from canvas, but then I get the error that the toImage method doesn't create ImageProvider<dynamic>.  I'll try saving as a png next, but that seems odd to have to write the Image out to png format?

Comment: how can we manage to increase or decrease the size of the thumb icon?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code.

```
class ToggleButtonScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ToggleButtonScreenState createState() => _ToggleButtonScreenState();
}

class _ToggleButtonScreenState extends State<ToggleButtonScreen> {
  bool _value = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: _value ? AssetImage("images/cnw.png") : AssetImage("images/cnw.png"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(AppDimens.EDGE_REGULAR),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  _normalToggleButton(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

Widget _normalToggleButton () {
    return Container(
      child: Transform.scale(
        scale: 2.0,
        child: Switch(
          activeColor : Colors.greenAccent,
          inactiveThumbColor: Colors.redAccent,
          value: _value,
            activeThumbImage: AssetImage("images/cnw.png"),
            inactiveThumbImage : AssetImage("images/simple_interest.png"),
            onChanged: (bool value){
             setState(() {
               _value = value;
             });
            },
        ),
      ),
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**pubspec.yaml**

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.3.2




dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.8.0"

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"

  assets:
    
     - assets/icon/google.png
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';


class MyChromeSafariBrowser extends ChromeSafariBrowser {
  @override
  void onOpened() {
    print("ChromeSafari browser opened");
  }

  @override
  void onCompletedInitialLoad() {
    print("ChromeSafari browser initial load completed");
  }

  @override
  void onClosed() {
    print("ChromeSafari browser closed");
  }
}

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    await AndroidInAppWebViewController.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
  }

  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp(), theme: new ThemeData(scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFFA7A5A5)),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final ChromeSafariBrowser browser = new MyChromeSafariBrowser();

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}


class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Image Button"),
    ),

      body:


      SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child:
        Column(children: <Widget>[



            Container(
                  // padding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Image.asset('assets/icon/Amazon_icon.png'),
                    iconSize: 50,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    splashColor: Colors.purple,
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await widget.browser.open(
                          url: Uri.parse("https://www.amazon.in/?&_encoding=UTF8&tag=bappasaikh-21&linkCode=ur2&linkId=e3b009b026920c3cfdd6185fadfb7e67&camp=3638&creative=24630"),
                          options: ChromeSafariBrowserClassOptions(
                              android: AndroidChromeCustomTabsOptions(
                                addDefaultShareMenuItem: false,),
                              ios: IOSSafariOptions(barCollapsingEnabled: true)));
                    },
                  ),
                ),
       
        









        ]),


      ),


    );
  }
}
```